# Negative Lookbehind Regex not working in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I wrote a piece of code in PHP that is intended to match an adverb (word ending in 'ly') that should **not** match any word that is daily, weekly, monthly, bi-daily, bi-weekly, etc.

For example, given the sentence `Locally meet daily for 3 days`, only `Locally` should match.

I nailed the Regex syntax using negative lookbehind, but PHP is throwing me an error:

> Compilation failed: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length at offset..

Here is my full code in PHP:

```
<?php
$sentence = "Locally meet daily for next 3 days";

// Use preg_match() function to check match 
preg_match('/(\w+ly)(?<!(daily|weekly|monthly))/', $sentence, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE); 

// Display matches result 
print_r($matches);
```

I have tried negative lookahead, but it is not giving me promising results. Would someone please suggest what could be done? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead, but it needs to be before your match group. You also need to add a word-break (`\b`) assertion at the beginning of the regex so that (for example) the regex doesn't match `aily` in `daily`, and another at the end so you don't match words with `ly` in the middle e.g. `newlywed`:

```
$sentence = "Locally meet daily newlywed for next 3 days";

preg_match_all('/\b(?!(?:daily|weekly|monthly))(\w+ly)\b/', $sentence, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE); 

print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Locally
                    [1] => 0
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Locally
                    [1] => 0
                )
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/krAar)

Comment: How would I be able to exclude words like bidaily, biweekly as well?

Comment: Either put those words into the alternation, or add `(?:bi)?` before it i.e. `\b(?!(?:bi)?(?:daily|weekly|monthly))(\w+ly)`

Comment: Thank you Nick. I solved it with: 
    `preg_match_all('/\b(?!(?:\w*(daily|weekly|monthly)))(\w+ly)/', $sentence, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);`

Comment: @solutionhacker that's probably simpler. Note it just occurred to me you need a word break at the end of the regex so that you don't match words with `ly` in the middle. See my edit.